# Debug run time current Form in c#

Tags: c#

I have numerous Form Applications in C#, and I want to debug the current running Form button event with a particular line, similar to how the current running Form in Visual Basic 6 is debugged by using the short key Ctrl+Break. Then I push the button or position the form where I want to begin the debugging process. Is there a debugging approach in C# that is similar to the Visual Basic 6 short key Ctrl+Break?

Comment: Can't you just place a breakpoint on the line you want to break at?

Comment: Or the event of the button ?

Comment: Or just *Break* by clicking the Break button or its shortcut? The shortcut appears if you hover over the Break button

Comment: You did not specify IDE. In Visual Studio, put breakpoint and press F5.

Comment: i am using visual studio 15 @Matt

Comment: @saeedahmed Then put a breakpoint where you need and just press Debug -> Start debugging or press F5. It will start program in debug mode.

Comment: You need to learn more about C#, check any tutorial

Comment: if breakpoints don't work for you you can write the `stop` command in visual basic, or with `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break` in c#. this will act as a breakpoint in debug mode and will cause the program to quit in release mode.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019. Quick check to the doc you may find everything you need in the debugger doc

Comment: I know making Breakpoint, i can start the application in debug mode but it is a long way, you know in visual basic 6 short way at runtime application  Ctrl+Break , debugging process start at the specific place @Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click the line which is you suspect and press f9 it put a breakpoint and then you can use:

- Step Into f11 : line by line debugging
- Step Over f10 : without debugging each line it just return result

And other tactic to learn use Console.WriteLine() in form application also. In output window you can see whatever write in writeline.
Also if you want to see variable's value, you can use watch window.

Comment: you know in the visual basic 6 short key ctrl+break, can break code at the current running form then step into one by one @Mert Akkanat

Answer (score 1):

To debug the code in Visual Studio, specify the breakpoint (by clicking the left side of line code) and then press the F5 key. Use F10 key to continue with step by step debugging.

Comment: I know making Breakpoint, i can start the application in debug mode but it is a long way,there if i have 300 forms , in this way whole application run then go the breakpoint , i want to go in debug mode when application is runing you know in visual basic 6 short way at runtime application Ctrl+Break , debugging process start at the specific place @mohammad dardaei